# MaaS shutdown node issue

Tags: shutdown, maas

So I've set up a MaaS server with about 8 nodes all commissioned and ready and everything works fine (on startup that is).  The problem is 2 of my nodes are set to power-up using "wake on lan" which works fine for starting up, but I can't seem to shut down those nodes using the web gui.  When I hit "Stop Node" the node does not shut down and remains powered on.  The other nodes that use IPMI have no problem shutting down or starting up.

Question: How do I get those two nodes (with power type set to WOL) to shut down remotely using the Web GUI?  Or is this not possible? I've searched for answers but I didn't find anything useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by modifying the power template for etherwake found in /etc/maas/templates/power/ether_wake.template.  The following modifications should fix your issue:

```
mac_address={{mac_address}}
power_change={{power_change}}
ip_address={{ip_address}}

if [ "${power_change}" != 'on' ]
then
    if [ -n "${ip_address}" ]
    then
       ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${ip_address} -C "echo 'sleep 2 && sudo /sbin/poweroff -f' | at now"
    else
       echo "Unable to power down a node using etherwake without ip address." >&2
       exit 1
    fi
elif [ -x /usr/bin/wakeonlan ]
then
    /usr/bin/wakeonlan $mac_address
elif [ -x /usr/sbin/etherwake ]
then
    if [ -n "${iface}" ]
    then
        /usr/sbin/etherwake -i "${iface}" $mac_address
    else
        /usr/sbin/etherwake $mac_address
    fi
else
    echo "No wakeonlan or etherwake program found." >&2
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Actually, this won't work.  There isn't really a good workaround for this, but it is possible to hack this template up a bit more to get a somewhat okay result.  The problem seems to be that {{power_change}} seems to always be "on" due to the fact that apparently it cannot adequately determine the power state transition of the node with WOL.  You can fake this feature by pinging the node to see if there's a reply and determining the power state transition based on that.